Salt error: "Jinja variable 'shell' is undefined"
I'm a little unclear as to why this error showed up. Loading users from pillar was working previously. I renamed a module from 'base' to 'common' to avoid confusion with the 'base' state in salt, and then this error appeared.
/pillar/top.sls:
base:
  '*':
    - common.users
  'appserver-*':
    - app-shared.users
  'ssh-bastion*':
    - ssh-bastion.users


/pillar/common/users.sls:
# Example User Entry
#
#  tusername:
#    fullname: Test Username (optional)
#    uid: 1007
#    gid: 1007
#    shell: /bin/zsh (optional)
#    groups: (optional)
#      - sudo
#      - ops
#    pub_ssh_keys: (optional)
#      - ssh-key # noqa: 204

users:
    
  foo:
    uid: 2000
    gid: 2000
    shell: /bin/zsh
    pub_ssh_keys:
      - ssh-rsa << obfuscated >> foo # noqa: 204

  bar:
    uid: 2001
    gid: 2001
    pub_ssh_keys:
      - ssh-rsa << obfuscated >> bar # noqa: 204

State file /salt/common/users.sls
{% for username, details in pillar.get('users', {}).items() %}
{{ username }}:
  {% do salt["log.info"]("Processing user "+ username) %}
  group:
    - present
    - name: {{ username }}
    - gid: {{ details.get('gid', '') }}

  user:
    - present
    - name: {{ username }}
    {% if 'fullname' in details %}
    - fullname: {{ details.get('fullname','') }}
    {% endif %}
    {% if 'shell' in details %}
    - shell: {{ shell }}
    {% else %}
    - shell: /bin/bash
    {% endif %}
    - home: /home/{{ username }}
    - uid: {{ details.get('uid', '') }}
    - gid: {{ details.get('gid', '') }}
    {% if 'groups' in details %}
    - groups:
      {% for group in details.get('groups', []) %}
      - {{ group }}
      {% endfor %}
    - require:
      {% for group in details.get('groups', []) %}
      - group: {{ group }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  {% if 'pub_ssh_keys' in details %}
  ssh_auth:
    - present
    - user: {{ username }}
    - names:
    {% for pub_ssh_key in details.get('pub_ssh_keys', []) %}
      - {{ pub_ssh_key }}
    {% endfor %}
    - require:
      - user: {{ username }}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

ec2-user:
  user.absent
ubuntu:
  user.absent

When I attempt to apply the state, I get:
~$ sudo salt-call state.highstate
[ERROR   ] Rendering exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 502, in render_jinja_tmpl
    output = template.render(**decoded_context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1291, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
    raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
  File "<template>", line 18, in top-level template code
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'shell' is undefined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 261, in render_tmpl
    output = render_str(tmplstr, context, tmplpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/salt/utils/templates.py", line 509, in render_jinja_tmpl
    raise SaltRenderError("Jinja variable {}{}".format(exc, out), buf=tmplstr)
salt.exceptions.SaltRenderError: Jinja variable 'shell' is undefined
[CRITICAL] Rendering SLS 'base:common.users' failed: Jinja variable 'shell' is undefined
local:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:common.users' failed: Jinja variable 'shell' is undefined

I don't understand how Jinja would complain about 'shell' being undefined when (to my eyes) any reference to 'shell' is enclosed in {% if 'shell' in details %}

PEBKAC
The problem was - shell: {{ shell }}. I looked at it several times and didn't see the obvious.
Just like the error said, shell is undefined. Replacing the entire if block to - shell: {{ details.get('shell', '/bin/bash') }} did the trick:
{% for username, details in pillar.get('users', {}).items() %}
{{ username }}:
  {% do salt["log.info"]("Processing user "+ username) %}
  group:
    - present
    - name: {{ username }}
    - gid: {{ details.get('gid', '') }}

  user:
    - present
    - name: {{ username }}
    {% if 'fullname' in details %}
    - fullname: {{ details.get('fullname','') }}
    {% endif %}
    - shell: {{ details.get('shell', '/bin/bash') }}
    - home: /home/{{ username }}
    - uid: {{ details.get('uid', '') }}
    - gid: {{ details.get('gid', '') }}
    {% if 'groups' in details %}
    - groups:
      {% for group in details.get('groups', []) %}
      - {{ group }}
      {% endfor %}
    - require:
      {% for group in details.get('groups', []) %}
      - group: {{ group }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

  {% if 'pub_ssh_keys' in details %}
  ssh_auth:
    - present
    - user: {{ username }}
    - names:
    {% for pub_ssh_key in details.get('pub_ssh_keys', []) %}
      - {{ pub_ssh_key }}
    {% endfor %}
    - require:
      - user: {{ username }}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

ec2-user:
  user.absent
ubuntu:
  user.absent

